# Did angels visit all Prophets and Messengers?

Tags: prophets, malaikah, messengers

Did Allah use angels as a medium of communication for all the Prophets and Messengers?

I have read that Allah spoke to Musa (AS). Was he also sent an angel (malak) later?

Comment: @Sassir Do we have any Quranic ayah or Sahih Hadith regarding it?

Comment: I tried to recall any who is talking about prophets and messenger son the whole but only remember one which gives different (three?) possibilities of communication between Allan and them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Did Angels visit all Prophets/Messengers?

Yes, of course. There are two angels that aways stay with us. A angel visits us right before we die and some other types of angels visit us during our lifetime. Angels visit everyone and therefore they visited all prophets and messengers (peace be upon them all).

### **Did Allah use angels as a medium of communication to all Prophets & Messengers?**

There is a specific angel whose job is to bring holy scripture to the messengers. He is jibraeel. He delivered the message of Allah to our beloved messengers. I don't **know** if it applies to prophets who didn't receive any scripture.